# ValueError: Shapes (None, 10, 10) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, speech-recognition

I found a speech recognition model online that I'm trying to get to run on my own computer.
The original code can be found here: https://github.com/sanjeevpalla/Speech-To-Text/blob/master/Speech-To-Text.ipynb

The model trains on the words:

```
words=["yes", "no", "up", "down", "left", "right", "on", "off", "stop", "go"]
```

When I am trying to train the model I get a fairly large error regarding the incompatible shapes:

```
Epoch 1/150
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/benja/anaconda3/envs/CNNEGCP548/codes/speech2text/speech2text16layers.py", line 179, in <module>
    history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=2, callbacks=[es,mc],validation_data=(cvX, cvY))
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 823, in _call    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 696, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3065, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **     
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:748 train_step       
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:204 __call__    
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:149 __call__
        losses = ag_call(y_true, y_pred)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:253 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1535 categorical_crossentropy 
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4687 categorical_crossentropy        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 10, 10) and (None, 10) are incompatible
```

Here is the relevant code/model:

```
# Model and training
INIT_LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 150
batch_size = 32
num_class = 10
#input_shape = (224,224,3) #(513, 800, 3)

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
#from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape, Lambda, GlobalAveragePooling2D

trainY = to_categorical(trainY, num_class)
testY = to_categorical(testY, num_class)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(2, 2),padding='same',activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(2, 2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2, 2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(2, 2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(2, 2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(2, 2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_class, activation='softmax')) 

model.summary()


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=25, min_delta=0.0001) 
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.hdf5', monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

#trainx is input data, trainy is target data, cvx and cvy represent validation set used to evaluate model performance at the end of each epoch
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=2, callbacks=[es,mc],validation_data=(cvX, cvY))


Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 48, 8)        40
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 48, 16)       528
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 64, 24, 16)        0
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 64, 24, 16)        64
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 64, 24, 16)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 24, 32)        2080
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 24, 64)        8256
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 32, 12, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 32, 12, 64)        256
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 32, 12, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 12, 128)       32896
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 12, 256)       131328
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 6, 256)        0
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 16, 6, 256)        1024
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 16, 6, 256)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 24576)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               6291712
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                2570
=================================================================
Total params: 6,470,754
Trainable params: 6,470,082
Non-trainable params: 672
_________________________________________________________________
```

The error 'ValueError: Shapes (None, 10, 10) and (None, 10) are incompatible' leads me to believe that there's an issue the very last layer which is the Dense layer its output is (None, 10). I've looked at similar problems and the solutions to those were to change the loss function from a categorical_crossentropy to a sparse_categorical_crossentropy however a new error occurs

```
Epoch 1/150
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/benja/anaconda3/envs/CNNEGCP548/codes/speech2text/speech2text16layers.py", line 176, in <module>
    history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=2, callbacks=[es,mc],validation_data=(cvX, cvY))
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 840, in _call    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2829, in __call__    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1843, in _filtered_call
    return self._call_flat(
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1923, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call     
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "C:\Users\benja\anaconda3\envs\529\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,10] and labels shape [3200]
         [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits 
(defined at c:/Users/benja/anaconda3/envs/CNNEGCP548/codes/speech2text/speech2text16layers.py:176) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1820]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I'm just starting out in my Neural Networks class and I'm trying to play around with this code I found and see if I can get it to work on my computer as it's intended and hopefully understand more on the way.

The original code can be found here:
https://github.com/sanjeevpalla/Speech-To-Text/blob/master/Speech-To-Text.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

How come do you have the shape of Y (N, 10, 10)???
It means you must have preprocessed wrong your data. You can have the shape (N, 10) if you use categorical_crossentropy, or (N,) if you use sparse_categorical_crossentropy.

Just revise the part of preprocessing of your code. And make sure that your Y have one of these shapes.

Comment: Well I'm unsure, like I said I just used a model I found online and my professor encouraged me to run it and play around with it, i'm not even sure where the preprocessing stage is in the original code, do you think you can help me understand?

Comment: Print out your Y, how does it look like?

Comment: here is the printout of my target dataset trainY

Target dataset trainY:  (14073, 10, 10)

Comment: Print the trainY[0] how it is? not just the shape.

Comment: Now i think you musk have done OneHot twice. You just need to remove one.

Comment: Just remove the 2 lines of to_categorical, i belive your Y must have been already one hot encoded.

Comment: Apologies thank you for your time, When printing out Y[0] =
 [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

looks like an 10x10 matrix

Comment: I've removed the lines of to_categorical earlier! The model is currently running thanks to your help I'm very grateful to you so far the model is still training on its first epoch. Hopefully it runs well for the rest of them! I can't wait to learn more in my class